# Don't show zero-values in BarChartModel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jqplot

How to hide zero-values in `org.primefaces.model.chart.BarChartModel`?

[image]

**Primefaces 5.2**

Comment: Wouldn't that mean removing the respective entries in the basic model? Besides that, would it even make sense not to show zero-valued bars?

Comment: @Thomas I tried to not put zero-values, but then model don't show any data

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39888

Comment: Just from my unexperienced view point: the data for the model would have to come from somewhere so if you remove the zero values right at the source (i.e. just provide the model with non-zero values) then it should work. I'd try not to change the model code itself.

Comment: @Thomas that doesn't work.

Comment: what if you substitute '0' with NULL? And please create an [mcve]

Comment: Show the code you use to fill the model, also if possible, show where your data come from.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: An [mcve] is always better than just 'the code to fill the model'. And where the data comes from is irrelevant. DB, File, whatever. Does not make a difference. An mcve with data from a plain `ArrayList` is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out decision. In order to hide zero values you should create js script in your xhtml file and then bind this script to model with org.primefaces.model.chart.BarChartModel.setExtender method.

```
<script>
        function extender() {
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
        showMarker: true,
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {show: true, location: 'n', ypadding: 0, hideZeros: true}
        };    
    }
</script>
```

Java Class:

```
BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();
model.setShowDatatip(false);
model.setShowPointLabels(true);
model.setExtener("extender");
```

xhtml

```
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{'javaClassController.getModel()'}"/>
```

Result should look like this:

[image: Bar Chart with no zero values]